# numerical methods and chaos, eulers method in excel

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eulers-method

this is my first post. I am trying to figure out this "exploration" for my high level college math class and I think trying to code in excel is messing me up.

"1. Consider the “simple” nonautonomous differential equation
dy/dt = e^t*sin(y).
Sketch the graph of the solution to this equation that satisfies the initial
condition y(0) = 0.3.
2. Use Euler’s method with a step size 1t = 0.3 to approximate the value of
the previous solution at y(10). It is probably easiest to use a spreadsheet
to carry out this method. How does your numerical solution compare to
the actual solution?
3. Repeat the previous calculation with step sizes 1t = 0.001,0.002, and
0.003. What happens now? This behavior is called sensitive dependence
on initial conditions, the hallmark of the phenomenon known as chaos.
4. Repeat step 2 but now for initial conditions y(0) = 0.301 and y(0) =
0.302. Why is this behavior called senstitive dependence on initial conditions?"

So I've solved the equation to be y(t)= 2(arccot(17.9858e^(-e^t))
and I've put =2(ACOT(17.9858*EXP(-EXP(t)))) into excel for different values of t and different initial conditions but everything gives my y(10)=3.141593, which I don't think should be happening right? the different initial conditions should be sending it into chaos.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the exact solution converges towards the next stable fixed point which is at $y=\pi$.

I'm not sure I would call the observations about the numerical solutions "chaos". You run into stability issues. For the Euler method stability requires that $L\Delta t\le 2$ at the most, better smaller like $\le0.5$, where $L$ is a $y$-Lipschitz constant of the equation. Here that gives $L=e^t$, which depends on $t$ and becomes rather large at $t=10$, $e^{10}=22026.5$

One can of course consider the Euler process at a fixed step size as a discrete dynamical system that has its own kind of chaos. But that has nothing to do with the properties of the exact solution